# How can I start new project from the Visual studio start menu?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, startmenu

In my Windows 7 Start menu, when I open the Visual Studio sub-menu, it shows my “pinned” projects and also my recently opened projects:

[image: Start menu with the Visual Studio menu opened]

This is quite useful and can speed up opening the project a lot (because I can do something else while Visual Studio and the project are loading).

But I often happen to create new temporary projects (especially when answering SO questions). Is there some way to streamline this too? Ideally, I'd like to add a shortcut among the pinned projects that creates, say, a new C# console application. Can I somehow modify the menu to add such shortcut? Or is there something else that achieves similar effect?

Comment: "Because I can do something else while Visual Studio and the project are loading" => I think It's easier to start Mass Effect 3 directly, without bothering to load a new VS project :) This way you'll get more FPS...

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to create a start-menu/taskbar shortcut to:

```
devenv.exe /command np
```

After clicking it you would need to choose the type and name for your project

You could also create a script that copies your template project and opens the new copy in VS.

Answer (score 0):

I use a common test solution "test.sln" that I reference when I need to open visual studio to try out some code. I just open the test solution and add another method. Then in my Main method, I just call the new method added.

If you are constantly adding new test projects and you don't need to keep them around, you can use [temporary projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yx39k28.aspx).

Comment: I already use temporary projects. I find that cleaner than using one solution for everything.